# Division (Transact-SQL) and Data Type Precedence with a decimal(38, 10) data type denominator

Tags: sql-server, division, decimal-precision

According to the documentation [/ (Division) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the result type is related to the [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), that said, in the following scenario, is there any way to receive the result type as a decimal(38, 10) ?

The calculation result seems loosing precision... A precise result should be 0.812356***7224***

```
declare @a decimal(38,10) = 0.8123567216;
declare @b decimal(38,10) = 0.9999999990;

select 
     [a] = @a
    ,[b] = @b
    , result1 = @a / @b
    , result2 = @a / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)
    , result3 = CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)
    , result4 = CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), (CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the resultant precision and scale for decimal division are noted in the table on [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). This is the relevant table entry:

> e1 / e2   p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)  max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)

The doc excerpt:

> In multiplication and division operations, we need precision - scale
> places to store the integral part of the result. The scale might be
> reduced using the following rules:
>
> The resulting scale is reduced to min(scale, 38 - (precision-scale))
> if the integral part is less than 32, because it can't be greater than
> 38 - (precision-scale). Result might be rounded in this case. The
> scale won't be changed if it's less than 6 and if the integral part is
> greater than 32. In this case, overflow error might be raised if it
> can't fit into decimal(38, scale) The scale will be set to 6 if it's
> greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this
> case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting type
> is decimal(38,6). Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the
> overflow error will be thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32
> digits.

This can be observed with `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'
declare @a decimal(38,10) = 0.8123567216;
declare @b decimal(38,10) = 0.9999999990;

select 
     [a] = @a
    ,[b] = @b
    , result1 = @a / @b
    , result2 = @a / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)
    , result3 = CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)
    , result4 = CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), (CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)))
        ',NULL,NULL);
```

| name | system_type_name |
| --- | --- |
| a | decimal(38,10) |
| b | decimal(38,10) |
| result1 | decimal(38,6) |
| result2 | decimal(38,6) |
| result3 | decimal(38,6) |
| result4 | decimal(38,10) |

If we reduce the integral part of the `result3` operands from `decimal(38, 10)` to `decimal(28, 10)`, the result type is the more precise `decimal(38, 10)`, sufficient for the 0.8123567224 value:

```
select 
        [a] = @a
    ,[b] = @b
    , result1 = @a / @b
    , result2 = @a / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)
    , result3 = CONVERT(decimal(28, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(28, 10), @b)
    , result4 = CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), (CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @a) / CONVERT(decimal(38, 10), @b)));
```